# generate c# classes from web service

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, visual-studio-2015

I have a problem that i cant generate c# classes in visual studio 2015
I guess the version of the soap is too old so the VS 2015 cant access it or figure it out

I tried using both service reference and web reference.

when I used soapUI application or eclipse IDE I can see the classes , only in visual studio it's not working.

I also noticed that visual stuidio adds "/?metadata" in the end of the web service download request

does anyone what can i do in this situation? 
[Link to the wsdl structure](https://ufile.io/h6nsr)

Comment: I doubt your problem is that the service is too old for VS 2015 to understand. But there are other ways, are you familiar with svcutil.exe? Have you tried pointing WcfTestClient.exe at it?

Comment: I tried using svcutil , but i get all kind of error, BTW with eclipse the web service is working (JAVA)

Comment: oh, is the web service written in Java? There can definitely be compatibility problems there. I have felt that pain and resorted to working directly with the xml via http calls.

Comment: Creating the service reference from the WSDL file gives this error - _"The document was understood, but it could not be processed.
  - The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.
  - There was an error downloading 'http://herbalife-mwruat2ws.hrbl.net:22000/AutoAttendant/AutoAttendantServices?SCHEMA%2FHLArtifacts%2FHLComponents%2FHLEnterpriseObjectLibrary%2FEBO%2FDistributor%2FV1%2FDistributorEBM_XSD'.
  - The remote name could not be resolved: 'herbalife-mwruat2ws.hrbl.net'
."_

Comment: The error is clear and verifiable, the reference URL is not accessible, you can test it by yourself.

Comment: @stuartd, I'm not sure you can say for certain that error is the same as OP is getting. Quite possibly, but a DNS issue does not really explain why it works in soapUI and Eclipse.

Comment: this URL is only acceptable via VPN.. thats why is not working

Comment: @crowcoder agreed, it was just context

Answer (score 1):

Open a Visual Studio "Developer Command Prompt" from the start menu and call wsdl.exe directly pointing it at the WSDL of your target service:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/7h3ystb6(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to contact Herbalife and get an updated WSDL.  In order for VS to import service references, it has to open all externally referenced assets.  In this case, there are at least five within the WSDL that point to `http://herbalife-mwruat2ws.hrbl.net:22000` -- and there is no HTTP service running there at this moment.  That's why it's failing.

We can't say what your Java code is doing, or why it's working in SOAPUI, but this is what you'll need in .NET.  Or, you could do things the very hard way and try to reverse-engineer what the Java code is doing.  I'd contact Herbalife.

Comment: this URL is only acceptable via VPN.. thats why is not working